# Subtract a value from each element of a std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector like `std::vector<float> myVector`. I have to subtract a `float` value from each of its elements. Using a `for` loop is very inefficient, as my vector is very large (5000+). I tried:

```
transform(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), myVector.begin(), bind2nd(std::minus<float>(), valuesToRemove[0]));
```

Where `valuesToRemove` is a `float` array.  But this does not change my original vector.

How do I do this in the correct way?

Comment: *Using a for loop is very inefficient as my vector is very long (5000+).* No matter what you do, it will be an O(N) operation. A `for` loop won't hurt at all.

Comment: :-( when I use for loop it takes a lot of time. I have to do this so many times inside my code. Is there another efficient way?

Comment: I don't think there is a way around

Comment: When it comes to dealing with all items in a `std::vector`, there isn't anything more efficient than O(N). You may want to rethink the higher level operations in your code. You might be able to sort the vector and work on a subset of the elements.

Comment: https://github.com/VcDevel/Vc

Comment: Are you sure `valuesToRemove[0]` is non-zero? [can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c66fd6911f859f61)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but it does not change my original vector. How do I do that in the correct way?

`std::transform` is for mapping a function over one range, and outputting into another range. `std::for_each` is an in-place analogue, that you could use.

> Using a for loop is very inefficient as my vector is very long (5000+)

Loop is the most efficient way to repeat an operation on a very long vector (on a (super)scalar processor).

I recommend following:

```
for(auto& element : myVector)
    element -= valuesToRemove[0];
```

---

Your loop may benefit from vector operations (SIMD). Make sure to let compiler tune for those if possible. If the compiler fails to vectorise the loop, you can explicitly unroll the iterations to expedite their use. If that fails, you could try using compiler intrinsics to vectorise manually at the expense of platform independence.

If your vector is long enough, and the process is repeated enough, then you might benefit from using a vector processor. Many desktop systems contain one in the form of a GPU. Modern GPU's provide an API to perform general vector calculations.

Comment: Even if the vector has many fewer elements or many (~1000), this method with a simple for loop has a lower execution time.

Comment: @user1929959 lower execution time than what?

Comment: @user2079303 thank you for your answer. Can you clarify these to mje: 1."Your loop may benefit from vector operations (SIMD). Make sure to let compiler tune for those if possible", 2. "try using compiler intrinsics to vectorise manually", 3. "If your vector is long enough, and the process is repeated enough, then you might benefit from using a vector processor." - yes my vector is long and process is continued repeatedly,

Comment: What sort of clarification do you need?

Comment: Also, if I update few vectors (say 5) at the same time like this, will it hinder performance more if I do not use for-loop?

Comment: clarification I need - how do I do these?

Comment: What were you planning to use instead of a for-loop?

Comment: 1. Check the manual of your compiler 2. Also check the same manual 3. Buy a vector processor and read its documentation.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. Can I use the same code of yours when updating more than one vector at the same time? Won't it be less performing than updating all the vectors in one loop?

Comment: I mean is there something like
for(auto& element : myVector, myVector2, myVector3)
element -= valuesToRemove[0];
where I can subtract same number from all or is the for loop only option?

Comment: @harsh separate loop for each vector is faster. Using single loop for separate vectors will cause cache thrashing.

Comment: Oh I thought the other way. Thanks a lot for all information.